# generate dynamic tabs from json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I want to generate dynamic tabs from my JSON with this function:

```
generateTab() {
    var tablist = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(jsonTest.tabList).length; i++) {
        tablist.push(<Tab>{Object.keys(jsonTest.tabList)[i]}</Tab>);
    }
    return tablist;
}
```

From this JSON object:

```
var jsonTest = {
    "tabList": {
        "titre" : "toto",
        "Activity" : {
            "A1" : {
                "titre": "A1 titre",
                "test" : "A1 test"
            },
            "A2" : {
                "titre": "A2 titre",
                "test" : "A2 test"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

At the end my function should return something like:

```
<Tab>titre</Tab>
<Tab>Activity</Tab>

<TabPanel> toto </TabPanel>
<TabPanel>
    A1: A1 titre A1 test 
    A2: A2 titre A2 test 
</TabPanel>
```

Any idea on how to generate the second part (TabPanel)?

Comment: And what exactly is the issue?

Comment: i don't know how to generate the tabpanel part

Comment: I am not sure I agree with the JSX structure you are expecting, what are `Tab` and `TabPanel`? Where are they defined? Isn't `TabPanel` supposed to be contained inside `Tab`?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi i am using https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs

Comment: @tetar if my answer accurately solves the problem you have, please don't forget to check it as the official answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct structure you are looking for is:

```
<Tabs>
    <TabList>
        <Tab>titre</Tab>
        <Tab>Activity</Tab>
    </TabList>

    <TabPanel>
        toto
    </TabPanel>
    <TabPanel>
        A1: A1 titre A1 test
        A2: A2 titre A2 test
    </TabPanel>
</Tabs>
```

You can achieve this structure using the following method in your component:

```
let jsonTest = {
    // ...
};

class YourApp extends Component {
    /**
     * Flattens the activities object into an array of strings
     * 
     * @param {object} activities the activities configuration object
     * @returns {array}
     */
    getFlattened(activities) {
        let results = [];
        for (let key in activities) {
            if (activities.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                results.push(
                    `${key}: ${activities[key].titre} ${activities[key].test}`
                );
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    /**
     * Genrates the tabs component structure
     *
     * @param {object} config the JSON tab configuration
     * @returns {JSX.Element}
     */
    generateTabs(config) {
        if (!config || !config instanceof Object) {
            return null;
        }

        let tabs = [];
        let tabPanels = [];

        for (let key in config) {
            if (config.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                tabs.push(
                    <Tab>
                        { key }
                    </Tab>
                );
                if (config[key] instanceof Object) {
                    tabPanels.push(
                        <TabPanel>
                            { this.getFlattened(config[key]) }
                        </TabPanel>
                    );
                }
                else {
                    tabPanels.push(
                        <TabPanel>
                            { config[key] }
                        </TabPanel>
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        return (
            <Tabs>
                <TabList>
                    { ...tabs }
                </TabList>

                { ...tabPanels }
            </Tabs>
        );
    }

    /**
     * React Lifecycle Rendering Method
     *
     * @returns {JSX.Element}
     */
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/* maybe other stuff here */}
                { this.generateTabs(jsonTest) }
                {/* maybe other stuff here */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```